# Using Azure storage file with SAS token in ViewerJs

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-storage-files

I generate SAS token for file in this way:

```
    private string GeFileSASToken(CloudFile file)
    {
        SharedAccessFilePolicy policy = new SharedAccessFilePolicy()
        {
            Permissions = SharedAccessFilePermissions.Read | SharedAccessFilePermissions.Write | SharedAccessFilePermissions.List,
            SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.Now,
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24),
        };
        return file.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy);
    }
```

If I open file link with this token in browser all works fine and file is downloaded. But If I try to use this link in Viewerjs like this:

```
<iframe src = "http://mydomain/ViewerJS/index.html#blob:https://myazureaccount.file.core.windows.net/myshare/mydirectorypath/myfile?SASTOKEN" width='300' height='300'></iframe>
```

I see error message:

Failed to load blob: https://myazureaccount.file.core.windows.net/myshare/mydirectorypath/myfile?SASTOKEN: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Answer (score 0):

Your C# code looks fine and I'm unable to reproduce the error you posted. Maybe you can use [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) to generate SAS token and see what happens.

[image]

**Update**

If your URL contains HTML special character, you will need to URL-encode them or just copy the SAS URL from Azure Storage Explorer which has been encoded.

[image]

Comment: The same result. Also if I delete SAS query string I see completely same error

Comment: Yes I cleared cache. I think something wrong with my Url for ViewerJs. Url should look like: domain+ViewerJS/#../+filePath. And this error happen because of domain part without SAS token, only file part have a SAS token in my Url

Comment: If your URL includes `#`, you'd need to encode it to `%23`.